# React Native - Cannot define multiple stacked navigators in a single file

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

index.js

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appname, () => App);
```

App.js

```
const App = createStackNavigator({route_X : {screen : X}});
const X = createStackNavigator(...);
module.exports = App;
```

From above code, I get this error.

> The component for route 'route_X' must be a react component

If I put X into a different file and import it, it working just fine. Am I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously in Javascript, everything must be value defined previously or otherwise it will become undefined. That's on me. So I just flip the code into this. And so on.

```
const X = createStackNavigator(...);
const App = createStackNavigator({route_X : {screen : X}});
```

The actual problem is in React Native itself. For the rest of the cases, when a variable is undefined or nullified on it's usage and a built-in function require it to be a value defined, it will give us undefined value error or exception. For example, "undefined is not an object". But in this case, the error result from the issue not saying anything about it, but yet it's still an error.

Answer (score 1):

as I think the problem is of the variable as you declared making conflict

**Updated**

```js
const tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  test: {screen: Screens.test},
},
{
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: false,
  tabBarOptions:
    {

      style: {
        borderTopWidth: 0.4,
        elevation: 6,
        borderColor: theme.colors.grey,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.inverse,
      },

      activeTintColor: theme.colors.active,
      inactiveTintColor: theme.colors.grey,
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: theme.colors.primary,
        borderBottomWidth: 1
      },
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: false,

    },
  })

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  tab: {screen: tab}
},{
  contentComponent: SideDrawer,
})

const test = StackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: Screens.SplashScreen
  },
  
  drawer:{screen: Drawer},
  
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <test/>
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

as I have used three navigators here.

Comment: i have 2 questions to ask you

Comment: 1. did you mean that it's suppose to has no problem to put parent and child navigators in single file? because i think it's probably my mistake somewhere too

Comment: 2. did you find anything wrong with my code? if it's not then i have to check somewhere else to find out

Comment: and do your X class component is extends with react component

Comment: you mean the very first screen in StackNavigator must extends Component and not another StackNavigator?

Comment: yes, the main navigator is stack in my case and the as you can see that I have mentioned the other navigator in the stack navigator.

Comment: but i'm a little confused. why the same rule not applied if the navigator is defined in different file?

Comment: when you insert in the app registry then you  have to add only one file and all other navigator should point to that file.

Comment: i've updated the question. i've followed exactly your example. but no luck. can you please tell me where am i wrong ? see code below the line

Comment: I have one question, why you want to add to stack navigator for only two screens.

Comment: I suggest you replicate my exact code first to reproduce the error